# Windows Phone 8 App Failed Certification

Tags: windows-phone-8

I recently submitted a very simple app to the WP app store that is basically  buttons that play sounds on click.
However, the app failed certification for the following reason(s):

Comments: Result: Fail
The application terminates unexpectedly in response to user input.
Steps to Reproduce:

1. Play music from music+videos hub and Launch the application.
2. Tap on any option from MY APPS NAME HERE.
3. Notice the application unexpectedly terminates.
   Comments: Result: Fail
   The application terminates unexpectedly in response to user input.
   Steps to reproduce:
4. Play music on the device from the Music + Videos Hub.
5. Launch the application.
6. Press the device's universal volume control.
7. Select "Pause" from the device's universal volume control.
8. Notice the application unexpectedly terminates.*

My questions are:
What is "the device's universal volume control" ?
How can I stop these errors from happening?

I used Blend to assign a sound to the buttons so there is no code to work with as far as I can see.

I've written similar apps for the Android market and always use a 'stop' and 'release' for each mediaplayer element at the beginning of each button's code. I'm assuming I need something similar here but not sure how to go about it in WP8. Any ideas?

Comment: Universal Volume Control appear when pressing the volume buttons on a handset. Controls will appear from the top with buttons to pause/play or skip your music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unviersal volume control refers to the phone physical volume buttons.

Did you have AdMod ads in your app? Recently i found an app with the same behavior failing certification and it was caused by AdMob control doesn't working right when the volume buttons show the volume popup over the app.

If you follow this link, you can see a workaround:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/vw61ZdJALYo

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. I do indeed have an Admob banner at the bottom of the screen. To be honest, as adding the sound was an option in blend, I assumed that Microsoft would be handling the environment. I think I will remove the blend 'sound' and declare and use the sound using C#. I know in Android I would normally use a sound.stop() and a sound.release(). Thanks you. Any more ideas are welcome.

Comment: Thanks again Josue. I just had time to read your supplied link and it seems the AdMob SDK is the culprit. THANKS  - you saved me hours of time digging around the WP8 sound API for no reason :)

Comment: UPDATE: I played with this last night and sure enough, if  I played a music track and launched my app and then clicked the sound button; the app crashed. So I added the code that is described in your link and it worked! No more crash . THANKS again Josue - I resubmitted my app :)

Comment: Awesome! I have the same problem in other apps... seems like google doesn't doing the right thing with that control and them doesn't even want to perform a fix... is a shame, they have the most revenue performance ad provider, but the control is a pain.